# What sort of person are we prohibited from serving them the meat of the pesach offering?

Tags: halacha, korban-pesach, apostasy

It says in sefer hachinuch that we are prohibited from serving meat of the pesach offering to an apostate.
For this prohibition to be in force, exactly what sort of person would be considered an apostate?

Answer (score 1):

[Sefer HaChinuch 13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaChinukh.13.1?lang=bi) defines what is meant by an apostate:

> שלא נאכיל מן הפסח לישראל מומר לעבודה זרה
>
> We may not feed meat of the Pesach offering to a Jew who has apostatized to idol worship.

(In this he is following the ruling of Rambam in [Hilchot Korban Pesach 9:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Paschal_Offering.9.7?lang=bi).)

It's worth pointing out that [Minchat Chinuch](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Minchat_Chinukh.13.1.1?lang=bi) suggests that one who desecrates *shabbat* may also fall into the category of one who is disqualified from eating of the Pesach offering.